# Separate file names from string

Tags: php, foreach, gravityforms

## FINAL SOLUTION

Hi all,

Here is the final code that I am using to upload a multi-file upload in GF. This code is tested and has been authenticated by my third party system.

```
 $form_id = $entry[ '1' ];
$upload_path = GFFormsModel::get_upload_path( $form_id );
$upload_url = GFFormsModel::get_upload_url( $form_id );

$arrPaths = str_replace( $upload_url, $upload_path, $entry[ 'x' ] );

$Paths = explode('","', substr($arrPaths, 1, -1));

$t=1;

foreach ($Paths as $key => $path) {
  $path =  str_replace('"', '', $path);
  $path =  str_replace('\/', '/', $path);
  $path =  str_replace('["', '', $path);
  $path =  str_replace('"]', '', $path);

$Paths[$key] = $path;

$add_client_files_POA = array(
  "strURL" => $path,
  "nClientId" => $clientId,
  "nContactId" => $contactId,
  "fileType" => rgar( $entry, 'y' ),
  "fileName" => "Proof of Address" . $t
);
if(!empty($add_client_share_three_payload['strURL'])) {
  $add_client_response = $client->UploadCtcFileURL($add_client_files_POA);
  }
$t=$t+1;
}
```

Thanks all for the help on this one. all comments got me to the final point.

Thanks Andrew

---

I have a string that is outputted in an array of files in Gravity Forms from a multiple file uplaod. I need to split each file into its own variable so that I can upload each of the files to an external server. The string is outputted like this:

```
"https:\/\/www.xyz.com\/folder\/sub-folder\/example1.jpg","https:\/\/www.xyz.com\/folder\/sub-folder\/example2.jpg","https:\/\/www.xyz.com\/folder\/sub-folder\/example3.jpg","https:\/\/www.xyz.com\/folder\/sub-folder\/example4.jpg"
```

I will need to separate each of these files and then run a function to upload each file individually as the API does not allow for multiple files to be uploaded at once.

I think I will need to run a *foreach* command but I need to strip the **""**, **,** and replace the **/** with  **/**. Is this possible?

My SOAP upload is as follows.

```
$form_id = $entry[ '1' ];
 $upload_path = GFFormsModel::get_upload_path( $form_id );
  $upload_url = GFFormsModel::get_upload_url( $form_id );
 $POI = str_replace( $upload_url, $upload_path, $entry[ 'y' ] );

    $add_client_files_POI = array(
        "strURL" => $POI,
        "nClientId" => $clientId,
        "nContactId" => $contactId,
        "fileType" => rgar( $entry, 'x'),
        "fileName" => rgar( $entry, 'x')
    );
    $add_client_response = $client->UploadCtcFileURL($add_client_files_POI);
```

I am using this function for my single file uploads and it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I thought it might be an explode, but how do I assign each file to a $?

Comment: I'd use `str_getcsv()` as `explode()` will fail if you have commas in the filenames.

Comment: If you explode on the "," you don't have that problem. Also gets rid of most of the " for you

Comment: Thanks, @AlexHowansky, I can see how that would work, but can I then take each value and assign it to a variable? I would then be able to replace the \/ with a str_replace

Comment: Will probably be easiest to loop over the exploded array and do your str_replace followed by the upload inside the loop

Comment: You can do something like `[$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4] = str_getcsv(...);` but this assumes you know exactly how many values will be in the list, and that it never changes. You're better off looping over the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//get paths with " removed
$arrPaths = explode('","', substr($paths, 1, -1));

foreach ($arrPaths as $path) {
  //change / characters
  $path =  str_replace('\/', '/', $path);
}
```

Edit:

```
//get paths with " removed
$arrPaths = explode('","', substr($paths, 1, -1));

foreach ($arrPaths as $path) {
  //change \/ to / characters
  $path =  str_replace('\/', '/', $path);

  $add_client_files_POI = array(
      "strURL" => $path,
      "nClientId" => $clientId,
      "nContactId" => $contactId,
      "fileType" => rgar( $entry, 'x'),
      "fileName" => rgar( $entry, 'x')
  );
  $add_client_response = $client->UploadCtcFileURL($add_client_files_POI);
}
```

Comment: Ok makes sense. Where do I call the $POI in this? and then would I run the $add_client_files_POI = array from within the foreach? Sorry, my PHP knowledge is super limited, I was thrown into the deep end by the client on this one

Comment: Inside of the foreach, the $path variable is set to one of the urls from your string. I believe that makes it equivalent to your $POI variable. So if you add the rest of your upload code inside that foreach either using the $path variable instead of renaming it $POI, I believe it would work. This would do the upload to each url separately, one per iteration of the loop. I will update my answer with what I am thinking.

Comment: I need to pull the original file from the GF structure - it is $form_id = $entry[ '1' ];
  $upload_path = GFFormsModel::get_upload_path( $form_id );
  $upload_url = GFFormsModel::get_upload_url( $form_id );

 $arrPaths = str_replace( $upload_url, $upload_path, $entry[ '407' ] );
 
 $arrPaths = explode('","', substr($paths, 1, -1)); is this correct? - It doesb't seem to be pulling the files

Comment: What exactly is stored in your `$upload_path` and `$upload_url` variables after calling the GFFormsModel functions??

Comment: It is the string that we are exploding. But I need to call it from a GF form and then from a GF field.